# For 2017 I have 3 different W-2s with 3 different addresses

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-2

In 2017 I was finishing my Spring semester in college. I had an internship from January-April, which I filed under 1 address. Then From May-August I moved to DC but subleased so didn't have an official address, however for my new internship I was filed under the address I lived at in DC. In September, I moved back to North Carolina for a full-time job, of course under address #3. So now I have 3 different W-2s under different employers with 3 different addresses. Will this be a problem when doing my taxes for 2017?

Comment: Nope, just do your taxes.  You will be fine.

Comment: Make sure the address you fill out on your 1040 is your current one.

Comment: You should probably explain more about your internship in DC. They have so many non-residents that their rules differ from most states.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the federal taxes, it is no problem at all.

For state taxes, just be aware that you probably had state tax withheld from multiple states. Look at your W-2’s closely to determine where all of your state taxes were sent. You may need to file a state tax return with more than one state.

Comment: ...and multiple cities, if you lived and/or worked in a city that levies income tax.